# Atlassian Bamboo CI + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, teamcity, mocha.js, bamboo

I use Atlassian Bamboo for my PHP projects and I find it extremelly useful, NodeJS is around since a while now and I'm really surprised that Bamboo does not support NodeJS out of the box. I read an [article about using Bamboo with NodeJS](http://iweinfuld.posterous.com/running-jasmine-tests-with-testacular-on-bamb) but it seems that it only applies for Bamboo OnDemand, I have setup Bamaboo on my server and from what I can see Jasmine is not supported in order to follow the article's steps.

Do anyone know how I could possibly could use Bamboo with NodeJS? I don't really mind the testing framework, I prefer mocha and vows but if there is any other testing framework that supports Bamboo I would use it.

Any hint would be helpfull!

PS: I'm not sure if TeamCity support NodeJS but from what I found on some quick google searches it seems that it is, could anyone confirm that for me? If TeamCity supports NodeJS then I'll switch over to TeamCity.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've probably seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935549/how-to-i-configure-teamcity-build-with-mocha), which suggests that TeamCity does work  with Mocha/Node.js

Comment: @JohnHoerr I didn't saw this to be honest! Thanks a lot I'm gonna look into it!

Answer (score 3):

Bamboo sure does support node.js - you just need to have node installed on your build server (this is the only difference between Bamboo download and Bamboo OnDemand) and use the JUnit Test Report task to pick up test reports by Testacular.

Comment: Hello, I have both Bamboo and NodeJS installed on the server could you point me to a guide that shows how to setup jUnit with testacular? From what I understood testacular will export the report to xml file and junit will use that xml to report back to Bamboo right?